# Meet endless restart when create unique constraint after neo4j-admin import

Tags: neo4j

I'm setting up a new neo4j v3.5.4 community instance. After install, considering my machine contains 32G RAM, I set the initial and max heap size for neo4j to 16G, and the page cache to 40G. Then I did below steps:

1. use neo4j-admin tool to import my data into db, which contains

```
  119263908 nodes
  221814590 relationships
  119263975 properties
```

2. start neo4j.
3. One of my node label is called "Contact", which contains a "tel" property. Since the tel for each contact is unique, I want to create unique constraint as below:

```
  CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Contact) ASSERT c.tel IS UNIQUE
```

Then I met the endless restart... As below log shown, neo4j starts to populate index, after several minutes, the graph.db becomes unavailable, then it restarts. After restart, it tries to populate the index, and after several minutes, it restarts again, endless. There is no exception or error in log.

```
2019-04-25 06:08:57.100+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Index population started: [:Contact(tel) [provider: {key=native-btree, version=1.0}]]
2019-04-25 06:14:03.535+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.m.e.CommunityEditionModule] No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'
2019-04-25 06:14:03.718+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Creating 'graph.db' database.
2019-04-25 06:14:03.795+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Requirement `Database available` makes database graph.db unavailable.
2019-04-25 06:14:03.798+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database graph.db is unavailable.
2019-04-25 06:14:03.853+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics START ---
...
.....
.........
2019-04-25 06:14:06.222+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Index population started: [:Contact(tel) [provider: {key=native-btree, version=1.0}]]
2019-04-25 06:19:11.935+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.m.e.CommunityEditionModule] No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'
2019-04-25 06:19:12.106+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Creating 'graph.db' database.
2019-04-25 06:19:12.186+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Requirement `Database available` makes database graph.db unavailable.
2019-04-25 06:19:12.188+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database graph.db is unavailable.
```

I have no idea why it happens. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you assigning 40g to pagecache when you only have 32g of RAM? Use `neo4j-admin memrec` to get a recommendation of how to configure your heap and pagecache, though for the sake of this operation, you may temporarily need more heap space for this to complete.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved this issue by reducing the page cache size.  The heap space is OK.